# What is the meaning of 今回のように?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrases

If you run 今回のように through google translate, it gives: "As of this time", and "Like this time", but nobody speaks like this in real english.

もちろん。
それだけじゃありません。
今回のように有名人を島にお招きするのも村おこしの一環なんです。

Of course, that isn't all. Inviting some famous guests 
is also another way of promoting our island.

Google translate gives the following bad translation:
It is part of the village revitalization to invite a celebrity to the island like this time.

Comment: "Like (we're doing) this time" would be perfectly natural English.

Comment: @user3856370 Thanks for replying! I can only assume that 今回のように in this case means something to the literal effect of "like we're doing on this occasion" or "like we're doing this time around". But more localized it would mean simple "like this". Since I'm not an expert nor a native Japanese speaker, I can only assume this to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

**~ (Noun) + のように** is a [grammar pattern](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n4-grammar-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA-no-you-nano-you-ni/) that can be used with any noun, and it means "to be similar to ~ / to be like ~". 
Here you are some example sentences using it with different nouns:

> 音【おと】**のように**速い飛行機【ひこうき】。
>   A plane fast **like** the sound.
>
> どうして俺【おれ】は彼【かれ】ら**のように**歌【うた】うことが出来【でき】ないんだ。
>   Why can't I sing **like** they can?
>
> 彼女は目を皿のようにして指輪を探した。
>   She looked for her ring with her eyes **like** plates. [i.e. with her eyes *wide open*].

(I love the last one since we have the same exact idiom in Spanish "ojos como platos" for to express that someone has their eyes wide open).

So, coming back to your expression, it translates as:

> 今回【こんかい】 → this time
>
> ~ のように → like ~ / similar to ~
>
> 今回【こんかい】**のように** → **like** this time

No need to learn it as an expression on its own, as long as you acquire the grammar pattern ~ のように it will make sense to you regardless of how you translate it into English.

As [user3856370 points out](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/7944/user3856370), a possible translation of the sentence would be:

> **今回のように**有名人を島にお招きするのも村おこしの一環なんです。
>
> **Like** [it is being done] **this time**, inviting famous guests is part of the village renewal [plan].

If it helps, you can imagine the speaker of such sentence could be a reporter covering some kind of news on a village renewal plan that is being carried out, or they could be the organisers of such event explaining what they are working on, etc.

Hope it helps!